# Ebean Queries AND and WHERE

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

I am using Ebean Model and have problem with writing queries

I have the SQL query as

> SELECT ABCODE FROM COUNTRY WHERE CountryDesc='India' and d_tag='N'

I am writing the ebean query as

> country.find().select("ABCODE").where().eq("CountryDesc","India").eq("d_tag","N")

(Country is finder object)

I can see these where(expression list) and and(expression arg0,expression arg1) but don't know how to pass the arguments.

Comment: Where's the problem ? Your Ebean query is rather correct, used like this it uses `AND` for each expression added after `where()`, doesn't it work for you ?

Comment: it works for me. But I am curious how can i use the where(Expr. arg0,Expr arg1) and "AND". is there some convention to follow about usage because logically both would give same results. if where() works why have they(ebean) have provided where(Expr) feature.